# Cannot Host Discord Bot on repl.it

Tags: python, replit

I recently made a discord bot and ran in on repl.it as it has free hosting (I use uptime robot). But, when I run main.py the uptime robot says that the website that I use for keep_alive() is "Down" and when I try to access the website from my browser it doesn't load either saying that the site "can't be reached". When I close the repl.it tab my bot goes offline as well.

Answer (score 1):

Repl.it is not made for hosting discord bot's it's prone to rate limits.

It's good for writing code online and hosting basic web apps or collaborating with others while coding.

You should definitely invest in a proper host like PebbleHost, PloxHost and etc if you need something to write code online. However, a VPS provider like Linode, Digitalcoean or even PloxHost would be more beneficial as you have your own dedicated IP and are not affected by rate limits from other users. However, this does require knowledge of Linux.

For your issue of your keep_alive you should try this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
import time
app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello World!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)#127.0.0.1 or ::

def keep_alive():  
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

Then in your `main.py`:

```py
from keep_alive import keep_alive
keep_alive()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had in keep_alive and main, but it was still down. Just checked again and it's up and running right now

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at UptimeRobot to send pings to the URL of the web server associated with the repl. [This video](https://dev.to/fizal619/so-you-want-to-make-a-discord-bot-4f0n) is for node.js but should apply to python as well on the UptimeRobot chunk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33356078)